# On a variation of Knopp's inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Well, I was confronted with a wonderful problem like this:

If $\{a_n\}$ is a positive sequence such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{a_n}<\infty$. Let $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$. Then for any $\alpha\geqslant0$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{na_n}{S_n} \right) ^{\alpha}\frac{1}{a_n}}<\infty 
$$
Moreover,my friend guesses that the following inequality may be correct
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{na_n}{S_n} \right) ^{\alpha}\frac{1}{a_n}}\leqslant2^{\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{a_n}}
$$
And the constant $2^\alpha$ is the best choice. For $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=1$, it's not hard to prove. But for $\alpha\in\mathbb R_+$, I don't know how to deal with it.

Or the equivalent inequality of integral like this:

$f(x)\geqslant0$,Let$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\mathrm dt$. Prove that
$$
\int_0^{\infty}{\left( \frac{xf\left( x \right)}{F\left( x \right)} \right) ^{\alpha}\frac{\text{d}x}{f\left( x \right)}}\leqslant 2^{\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\text{d}x}{f\left( x \right)}}
$$
The inquality may be right only for$0\leqslant\alpha\leqslant2$.

Any advice will be appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: By Knopp's inequality $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{S_n}< 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}$$ and the slightly stronger $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2n+1}{S_n}<4\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}$$ also holds, hence I bet that the claim can be proved by combining this inequality with Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By Knopp's inequality (see pages 109+ of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)) we have 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{S_n}< 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}\tag{1}$$
and by Holder's inequality, for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{n}{S_n}\right)^{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{1-\alpha}\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{S_n}\right)^\alpha\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{1-\alpha}\stackrel{(1)}{<}2^\alpha\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}\tag{2} $$
as claimed. The optimality of such inequality should not be difficult to check by considering $a_n=n$ for any $n\leq M$ and $a_n=n(n+1-M)$ for any $n\geq M$. The discrete version implies the continuous version by approximations through simple functions.

Comment: Thank you very much！You have done a good job.But you only solved the condition $0＜\alpha \leq 1$. For $\alpha＞1$，conld you please give me some hints？Thanks again！

Comment: @Renascence_5.: correct, I still have to study the case $\alpha\in[1,2)$ in depth, and I am not even sure the given inequality holds in such a case. I will perform some experiment and keep you posted.